# How to Filter an Array of Object and check if Specific key has a value in an Array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have this Array of Objects:

```
const Books = [
  {title:'Book 1', Date: '12/12/2000'},
  {title:'Book 2', Date: '12/12/2001'},
  {title:'Book 3', Date: '12/12/2003'},
  {title:'Book 4', Date: '12/12/2003'}
]
```

I have this Array of selected Books:

```
 const selectedBooks = ['Book1','Book4']
```

Is it possible to obtain a result of:

```
 const filteredBooks = [
     {title:'Book 1', Date: '12/12/2000'},
     {title:'Book 4', Date: '12/12/2003'}
 ]
```

Is there a method in lodash or ES6 to implement it?

Comment: In selectedBooks array title is `Book1` and in books array title is `Book 1` is it right or you are getting a title like that in selectedBooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the items in `selectedBooks` will match the `title` in `filteredBooks`. If not, you'll need some way to map those values.

You want a combination of [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
const filteredBooks = Books.filter(book => selectedBooks.indexOf(book.title) !== -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const Books = [
    { title: 'Book 1', Date: '12/12/2000' },
    { title: 'Book 2', Date: '12/12/2001' },
    { title: 'Book 3', Date: '12/12/2003' },
    { title: 'Book 4', Date: '12/12/2003' }
]

const selectedBooks = ['Book 1', 'Book 4']

const filteredBooks = Books.filter(book => selectedBooks.includes(book.title));

console.log(filteredBooks);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` for all the elements for which `selectedBooks` `includes` their `title`:

```js
const filteredBooks = Books.filter(book => selectedBooks.includes(book.title))
```

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns all entries for which the given callback returns a truthy value, and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) will tell you whether the array contains the given value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try array filter operator

```
const filteredBooks = Books.filter(({title}) => selectedBooks.includes(title))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const books = [
    { title: 'Book 1', Date: '12/12/2000' },
    { title: 'Book 2', Date: '12/12/2001' },
    { title: 'Book 3', Date: '12/12/2003' },
    { title: 'Book 4', Date: '12/12/2003' }
];

const selectedBooks = ['Book 1', 'Book 4'];

const filteredBooks = _.filter(books, book => _.includes(selectedBooks,  book.title));

console.log(filteredBooks);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```